# sql server is not responding when 1700 users are facing the portal and table is having 25 lacks records

Tags: sql, performance, deadlock

This is Ashish i am having performance issue in my portal i am using these things in my SQL server:

1. SSIS package to get the online data every 15 mins
2. table is having 25 lacks records (this data is not syncing from online this is only portal data)
3. 1700 uses are using portal and and big table is updating in inserting every sec
4. indexes are rebuilding every in the morning and statics are there
5. Server is having 54 GB RAM and application and data base server is same
6. Syncing of Online data (TimeSheet Time phased data ) to SQL every day at 12
7. Uses are not able to fill timesheet on Friday and Monday because everyone fills timesheet on these days

Please help me

Comment: Too broad, go and buy a book on system-scalability; you'll find all your answers.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you can post query, Might need fine tuning.FInd out blocked process first and high impact query on Database. I guess users get time out at certain times due to blocked process

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.sysprocesses WHERE blocked <> 0;
SELECT * FROM dbo.sysprocesses WHERE spid IN (SELECT blocked FROM dbo.sysprocesses where blocked <> 0)
```